# Given path is being changed to "/"

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that seeks for old files in a given directory (`/new`) and zips them to another one (`/old`):

```
#!/bin/bash
export TAG="archive"
export NEW_DIR="/new"
export OLD_DIR="/old"
export FILE_RETENTION=2      

# function to zip a file to OLD dir and remove it from NEW
function zip_rm(){
    f_name=`basename "$1"`
    source_base=`dirname $1`
    [[ "$source_base" == "${NEW_DIR}" ]] && dest_base=${OLD_DIR}
    dest="${dest_base}/${f_name}.zip"
        logger -p local0.info -t "$TAG" "archiving ${1} to $dest"
        out=`zip -j "${dest}" "${1}"`
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && logger -p local0.err -t "$TAG" "zipping ${1} failed: $out"
        out=`/bin/rm -f "${1}"`
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && logger -t -p local0.err "$TAG" "removing ${1} failed: $out"
}

export -f zip_rm

logger -p local0.info -t "$TAG" "archive procedure started"

if [ -d "${NEW_DIR}" ]; then
        logger -p local0.info -t "$TAG" "archiving ${NEW_DIR} started"
        find ${NEW_DIR} -daystart -mtime +${FILE_RETENTION} -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 0 -I {} bash -c 'zip_rm "$@"' _ {} 
        logger -p local0.info -t "$TAG" "archiving ${NEW_DIR} ended"
fi
```

This works as expected when the files are located in the `$NEW_DIR` - the files older than `$FILE_RETENTION` are zipped out to the `$OLD_DIR`.

However, when the files are located under the subdirectories, like `$NEW_DIR/ABC , $NEW_DIR/DEF`, they **not** being zipped to `$OLD_DIR`, but to the **"/"** with the name of the filename only.

I cannot figure out why the `$dest_base` changes to **"/"** whereas it is statically assigned as `dest_base=${OLD_DIR}`.

Moreover, "`find`" command locates all the files in subdirectories with their absolute paths.

My expectation that ALL the files from `$NEW_DIR` would be zipped out to `$OLD_DIR`, and the files from the subdirectories - to `$OLD_DIR/subdirname/$dest`

Where my mistake is?

Please explain.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the lines that cause the problem:

```
source_base=`dirname $1`
[[ "$source_base" == "${NEW_DIR}" ]] && dest_base=${OLD_DIR}
```

Since `dirname new/ABC/file` outputs `new/ABC`, `source_base` is not equal to `NEW_DIR`, so `dest_base` remains unset and `${dest_base}/${f_name}.zip` expands to `/file.zip`.

Comment: makes much sence... what would be the best approach to achieve the desired with as generic way as just possible? I mean i wouldn't like to assign multiple variables

Answer (score 1):

Based on @oguzismail's comment i achieved the goal with

```
source_base=$(dirname "$1" | cut -f 1-2 -d "/")
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, because the "old" directory is being rotated once a while. With current approach all files from "new" and subdirectories are being zipped into the "old" without sorting to dirs, and then deleted.